# 'undefined reference' errors when compiling against library

Tags: c, unix

I added a third party library to my code and is getting errors like this when running `make`. Please help me understand this error.

```
(.text+0x9b4): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
/home/bet/Tent/tun/app/Common/hl/lib/libGHAL.a(gfxhal.o): In function `GFX_create_region':
/home/bet/Tent/tun/app/Common/hl/src/GHAL/gfxhal.c:1141: undefined reference to `my_key_handler'
/home/bet/Tent/tun/app/Common/hal/src/GHAL/gfxhal.c:1141: undefined reference to `create_window'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [all] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/bet/Tent/tun/app/Common/c_app'
make[1]: *** [ctv_all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bet/Tent/tun/app/Common'
```

Comment: Does the third-party library provide a mechanism for adding the correct linking flags?  pkg-config?

Answer (score 7):

Those are Linking errors, which tell you the linker cannot find definitions for the library you are using.
You will have to link the library to your project.

```
gcc <your files for compilation> -lLibName
```

Read **[this](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html)** for better understanding.

Comment: Assuming that the libraries and include files are installed on the 'standard' locations where the toolchain will look for them.

Comment: The link is dead (at the history of this comment)

Answer (score 0):

I still get the error even if

1. `readline` library is installed and
2. `-lreadline` is added to `gcc` compiling command.

The root cause of my issue is the order of the libraries/code: `-lreadline` (and other libraries) should be put right before `-o` options.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. you would be better off asking a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), giving all relevant details (see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking a good question).